# Jenkins build history "More" link

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was using Jenkins 1.609.1 and when looking at a jobs build history, there was a "More" link that showed all of the build history.  I am now trying to use Jenkins 2.89.3 and the "More" link is not visible.  I have more than 30 builds in the builds folder.  The job is setup to store the build for 30 days and the artifacts for 8 days.  How do I get the "More" link, so that all builds are visible?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `hidden build history Page` Navigation section. when you hover on any build inside `Build History` section then you can see three arrows next to this section.

Attaching screenshot for your reference.[image]

Comment: I see the navigation section, but when I push on the older arrow, nothing happens.

Comment: I have a large number of pending jobs in the queue.  When I am on the jobs page, the navigation arrows don't work.  On another jobs page, there is only the executing job and no jobs in the queue.  The navigation arrows work on this screen.